# How to add second button without stack collapse?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state, setstate

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
    this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this)
  }
  clicked(){
    this.setState(prevState =>{
      return { 
        count : prevState.count+1
      }


    })
  }
  doubled(){
    this.setState(doubleState =>{
      return { 
        count : doubleState.count+2
      }


    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.state.count}
        </h1>
        <button onClick={this.clicked}>changed</button>
        <button onClick={this.doubled}>changed and doubled</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

My question is: How to add second button "doubled" without crash? I'm newbie in react, so please dont blame. First button is working, but with the second i have some problems. Should I write the second class or it can work in one class?

Comment: The only difference between your 2 buttons is that you only bind the "clicked" 
`this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this)`.

Comment: oh.. of course, thank you, forgot about binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not bind your `doubled()` function. This means it will run as soon as the button is rendered. This will in turn update the state, which will re-render and cause an infinite loop of rendering and you will hit max call stack limit.

You need to add `this.doubled= this.doubled.bind(this)`